# Can I convert .png data into an Int in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiimage, swift4.2

I convert an image into .png data from a `UIImageView` and print result on console with this code:

```
    let img = img_view.image!.pngData()
    print(img)
```

The result of this snippet is `232206 Bytes`
Can I get only `232206` as integer output, without the "bytes" suffix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the size (number of bytes) of the `Data`, which you can access by [`.count`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/2946901-count):

```
let sizeOfData = img.count // 232206
```

After all, `Data` represents a collection of bytes, so it conforms to `Collection`, which has the `count` property.

Answer (score 0):

Use `count` property:

```
    let imgData = imgView.image!.pngData()
    let imgBytesCount = imgData!.count
    print(imgBytesCount)
```